# Array se divide sozinho quando os elementos dentro dele passam de 100 durante o post da api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array, arraylist

Estou tentando fazer um post para minha api porem quando a quantidade de itens no meu array ultrapassa 100 ele se divide ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas minha api só aceita este array quando ele fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu devo fazer para o array não se dividir?

Codigo de chamada

```
try {
    $http({
        url: $rootScope.raiz_ws + "/xxxx/Gravar?parametro=" + $scope.pesq.parametro,
        method: "POST",
        data: { 'Itens': $scope.pesq.listpesq }
    }).then(function (response) {
        alert(response.data.mensagem);
        $scope.Pesquisar();
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Isso é só na visualização pelo console. A array é contínua, não tem essas divisões.

Comment: porem isso não ocorre quando vou fazer a chamada da api...